# Websocket.disconnect() method throws java.net.SocketException: Socket closed

Tags: android, websocket

I am using android-websockets library from codebutler in my project. But I ran into problem when I execute `disconnect()` method. Following is the code:

```
public void disconnectServer()
{
    if(client != null)
    {
        try {

            if(client.isConnected())
            {
                client.disconnect();

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I get the following exception:

> 05-11 17:58:19.873: W/System.err(29443): java.net.SocketException:
>   Socket closed
>
> 05-11 17:58:19.873: W/System.err(29443): at
>   libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native Method)
>
> 05-11 17:58:19.873: W/System.err(29443): at
>   libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:161)
>
> 05-11 17:58:19.873: W/System.err(29443): at
>   libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:250)
>
> 05-11 17:58:19.878: W/System.err(29443): at
>   libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:553)
>
> 05-11 17:58:19.878: W/System.err(29443): at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:485)
>
> 05-11 17:58:19.878: W/System.err(29443): at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:37)
>
> 05-11 17:58:19.878: W/System.err(29443): at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:237)
>
> 05-11 17:58:19.878: W/System.err(29443): at
>   libcore.io.Streams.readSingleByte(Streams.java:41)
>
> 05-11 17:58:19.878: W/System.err(29443): at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:233)
>
> 05-11 17:58:19.878: W/System.err(29443): at
>   java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:75)
>
> 05-11 17:58:19.878: W/System.err(29443): at
>   com.codebutler.android_websockets.HybiParser.start(HybiParser.java:120)
>
> 05-11 17:58:19.878: W/System.err(29443): at
>   com.codebutler.android_websockets.WebSocketClient$1.run(WebSocketClient.java:145)
>
> 05-11 17:58:19.878: W/System.err(29443): at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Please help!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the implementation of disconnect() method does not synchronize with the thread which is created in the implementation of connect() method. [codebutler/android-websockets](https://github.com/codebutler/android-websockets) is not of commercial quality. The disconnect() method does not perform even the [closing handshake](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-7.1.2) which is required by [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455).

Use another WebSocket library if you don't want to see the error.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply. Can you please suggest any library for commercial use? I have tried using two libraries viz., java_websocket & codebutler/android-websockets but it is giving me problems. Apart from the problem that I have mentioned above, I am facing a serious problem of socket disconnection. I don't know why it gets disconnected if I keep it idle for sometime. I get NotYetConnectedException when I try to call any APU in my project. Can you please suggest me any library which can be used for commercial use?

Comment: Try **[nv-websocket-client](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client)** ([Blog](http://darutk-oboegaki.blogspot.jp/2015/05/websocket-client-library-java-se-15.html)). To keep a connection, you need to send [Ping](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-5.5.2) (or unsolicited [Pong](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-5.5.3)) periodically. `nv-websocket-client` provides `WebSocket.setPingInterval` method to do it very easily. See [JavaDoc](http://takahikokawasaki.github.io/nv-websocket-client/) for details.